# Shrink cells selected by 1 on each side

Tags: excel, vba

When a user selects a certain range of cells, for example A1:A10, I want the macro to shrink the selection down to A2:A9. I've only managed to get the addresses of the selected cells so far.

I'm quite new to VBA so an example would be quite appreciated
Thanks!

```
Sub macro1()
    Dim addr As String
    addr = Selection.Address
    MsgBox addr

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please note that SO is not a code writing service. You are required to make your own research, attempt and if you are stuck, post here with a question with your code attempt.

Comment: @RaymondWu I have added what I have attempted so far

Comment: Please don't provide code in images.. Post it as a code block. Help us to help you by making it easy for everyone to test your code.

Comment: @RaymondWu Uploaded :)

Comment: Your code doesn't seems like an attempt at all, what exactly are you stuck at? @XiTe

Comment: @RaymondWu I don't know to select the individual row and column values so that I can change the selection

Comment: This is how you select: `Range("A1:A9").Select`, from your question - So if the user select exactly `A1:A10` then you want it to change to `A2:A9`? Your image doesn't show what you said anyway, your question is asking to shrink 1 row on each side but your image shows shrink 1 column on each side. @XiTe

Comment: That is correct, however with the range that I am selecting the values will be changing the whole time, I want it to be dynamic in the way that if I selected A100:A120 it would then change to A101:A119. @RaymondWu

Comment: You have to be explain in details then, so this "shrinking" will happen every single time you select? if not then what's the condition? @XiTe

Comment: I am basically working on a spreadsheet with a lot of missing fields, I am currently selecting each column manually myself. using a 3rd party macro to fill in the missing values with a growth trend, then manually selecting the values that were initially missing and giving them a color. Hope that makes sense! @RaymondWu

Comment: You aren't answering my question at all. You don't need to select cells to perform action with them (in fact it's bad practice). Since you are using another macro to filling the missing value, why not modify that code to give the color as well? Do you have access to the code? @XiTe

Comment: Unfortunately the third party macro program is just a set of keystrokes that I recorded: https://imgur.com/a/0w3NFK9. I have read around a bit and someone suggested using range.offset and range.resize to achieve what I am trying to do. @RaymondWu

Answer (score 1):

This will shrink your selection by 1 column on each side (only works if there are at least 3 columns select):

```
Sub ShrinkSelection()
    With Selection
        If .Columns.Count > 2 Then
            .Cells.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 2).Select
        Else
            MsgBox "Selection must have at least 3 columns."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why `.Cells(0)`? using that your code does not work if you select `A1:C5`. You need to change it to `.Cells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(ColumnSize:=.Columns.Count - 2).Select` to make it work properly.